# Pygame examples not found in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pygame

I want to learn how to code in Pygame (python3.8.5, Ubuntu 20.04). I got pygame installed but it can find the examples. I tried to search for them manually and didn find them either. It seems that the examples were not installed at all.

Here's what I did so far:

The attempt to install pygame with pip failed due to tons of failed dependencies.

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

After searching a bit, I found this command, which installed pygame:

```
sudo apt install python3-pygame
```

But it fails when I try to run one of the examples:

```
user:~$ python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens

pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'pygame.examples.aliens' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.examples')
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Package Maintainers have elected to [not include the examples](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/python3-pygame/filelist) in python3-pygame. Tests and docs are also excluded.

You can access the [examples](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/tree/master/examples) from the [pygame](https://github.com/pygame/pygame) github repository.